# Devise Registrations Controller santize_for_mass_assignment Error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my project, whenever i try to register a new user, i get the error

```
NoMethodError - super: no superclass method `sanitize_for_mass_assignment' for #<User:0x007f130c708f20>:
  activemodel (4.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
  strong_parameters (0.1.4) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:8:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:559:in `init_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
```

In my project, I have done the following

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registerable

end
```

I created a custome registrations controller as follows:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

  private
    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

I am confused why i am getting this error, I am using rails 4.2.1 and Devise 3.5.2

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issues and you have installed gem 'strong_parameters' please remove it because it has been added in ActiveModel and ActiveController since Rails 4.0. Documentation got me confused so i added the gem and tht caused my error.